# UI elements became not visible in iOS 13

Tags: swift, user-interface, uinavigationcontroller, mkannotationview

After updating my iPhone to iOS 13 one of my app is missing some UI elements

1. back bar button item in navigation controller which is declared in viewDidLoad like that:

```
navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: NSLocalizedString("Cancel", comment: "Cancel"), style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(handelCancel))
```

I can dismiss view controller by swiping down and still can press on the place where leftBarButtonItem should be to perform func handelCancel. So button is invisible but it is still there

[image: screenshot 1]

2. I have clustered annotations on mapKitView which is declared in viewDidLoad like that:

```
mapKitView.register(ClusterView.self, forAnnotationViewWithReuseIdentifier: MKMapViewDefaultClusterAnnotationViewReuseIdentifier)
```

and have custom class:

```
class ClusterView: MKMarkerAnnotationView {

    override var annotation: MKAnnotation? {
        willSet {
            markerTintColor = UIColor(r: 247, g: 154, b: 16)

            let button = UIButton(type: .detailDisclosure)
            isEnabled = true
            rightCalloutAccessoryView = button
        }
    }
}
```

It became impossible to see clustered annotations, but if I zoom in annotations are there.

On devices with iOS 12 everything works fine. What changes should I make to make these elements visible again?

Comment: are you sure there is no button? or maybe it's just invisible? what is the tint colour of your navigation bar? What is the difference in setting the left button and the right one? Do you rely on a tintColor for your item or you use textAttributes to style it? Did you read about `UIBarButtonItemAppearance` - some of the old styling (not tintColor though) doesn't work on iOS 13 anymore?